# before_filter in application controller for only get requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

I need to set up a before_filter in my ApplicationController that redirects a user if they have not yet agreed to a new terms of service. However, I want to restrict the filter to only run based on the type of request.

I'd like to write something like this:

```
class ApplicationController

before_filter :filter, :only => {:method => :get}
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
before_filter :do_if_get

private

  def do_if_get
    return unless request.get?

    # your GET only stuff here.
  end
```

Or more simply

```
before_filter :get_filter, if: Proc.new {|c| request.get? }

private

  def get_filter
    # your GET only stuff here.
  end
```

Comment: There should be a comma between `:get_filter` and `:if`. Tried to edit, but SO requires a six character change minimum

Answer (score 0):

Compliments to deefours answer, this also work with `Sinatra::Request`

```
before do
  something if request.get?
end
```